# How to update an array with WritableKeyPath in Swift 4.0

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, updating, keypaths

In Swift 4.0, I have an array of structs. Is there a way to use keyPaths to update all items in the array without using manually iterating like map or forEach? Something similar to objc `[people makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(setName:) withObject: @"updated"];`

```
struct Person {
    var name: String? = "Empty"
}
var people = [Person(), Person()]

//This only updates one person:
people[keyPath: \[Person].[0].name] = "single update"

//I'm looking to accomplish something like this without a map
let updatedPeople = people.map { (person: Person) -> Person in
    var copy = person
    copy[keyPath: \Person.name] = "updated"
    return copy
}
```

something like 
    people[keyPath: \[People].all.name] = "update all without manually iterating"

Comment: `people.indices.forEach { idx in people[idx][keyPath: \Person.name] = "updated" }`

Comment: Nothing to do with key paths, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mutating into a member of an array requires an l-value. Swift's mechanism for l-values is the subscript, so we can use that:

```
for i in people.indices {
    people[i][keyPath: \Person.name] = updated
    // or more simply, just:
    // people[i].name = "updated"

    // This even works too, but I can't see any reason why it would be desirable
    // over the other 2 approaches:
    // people[keyPath: \[Person].[i].name] = "update"
}
```

You could also use `forEach`, but I generally only recommend that over `for` in cases where you have an existing closure/function to pass in which has type `(Index) -> Void`:

```
// meh
people.indices.forEach {
    people[$0][keyPath: \Person.name] = "updated"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT** Responding to your now edited question asking where is the Swift equivalent of `[people makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(setName:) withObject: @"updated"]`, the simple answer is that `map`, which you for some reason reject in your question, *is* that equivalent. Of course, to do what Objective-C does, we have to use the Objective-C style of object type, namely a class:

```
class Person {
    var name: String? = "Empty"
}
var people = [Person(), Person()]
people = people.map {$0.name = "updated"; return $0} // *
```

The starred line *is* how you make the objects in the array perform the "selector".

A struct is a value type, so as you rightly said in your question, we have to insert a temp variable with a `var` reference:

```
struct Person {
    var name: String? = "Empty"
}
var people = [Person(), Person()]
people = people.map {var p = $0; p.name = "updated"; return p}
```

---

[Original answer:]

The use of key paths in your question seems to be a red herring. You're just asking how to set a property of all the structs in an array.

`map` is just a way of cycling through the array. You cannot magically do this *without* cycling through the array; if you don't do it explicitly, you have to do it implicitly.

Here's an explicit way of doing it:

```
struct Person {
    var name: String? = "Empty"
}
var people = [Person(), Person()]
let kp = \Person.name
for i in 0..<people.count {
    people[i][keyPath:kp] = "updated"
}
```

That's not actually any more efficient than using `map`, though, as far as I know; structs are not mutable in place, so we are still filling the array with entirely new Person objects, exactly as we would have done if using `map`.

Comment: Would recommend `people.indicies` over `0..<people.count`. We get way too many index-out-of-bounds errors arising from the common typo: `0...array.count`

Comment: @Alexander Spelling it correctly would help, I presume.

Comment: well, yeah. Point stands, however.

Comment: Well, you've given that in your answer, so I think I'll leave mine as is.

Comment: Not asking for magic, asking if there are any built in helpers that I am missing like an obj-c you can `[people makeObjectsPerformSelector: @selector(setName:) withObject: @"updated"];`

Comment: @joels That is a totally different question, but even so, no there's no magic notation that's distributive over an array, exactly because `map` (which Objective-C lacks) does that kind of job. `people = people.map { $0.name = "updated"; return $0 }` _is_ how you do that sort of `makeObjectsPerformSelector` in Swift. But of course that requires that your object be a class, not a struct. It's another language, another way of speaking. But it's not worse.